# How to truncate a row based on column data?

Tags: mysql, sql, row, truncate

For example if characterid = null I want the entire row removed: example of what I want removed:

[image: http://puu.sh/mhveP/b2df36f6cc.png]

but if characterid has a value then I want to keep the entire row: example of row I want to keep:

[image]

Obviously I can remove the rows myself manually but it would take way to long to do them all.

Comment: `where characterid is null`

Comment: Also truncate in MySQL empties a table completely: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html  The command you want is delete.

Comment: @amdixon even if simple, post an answer as your comment is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql select on fields containing null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097890/mysql-select-on-fields-containing-null-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A delete query is pretty similar to a select query except that it says `DELETE FROM` instead of `SELECT * FROM`.  You would run your delete like so:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE characterid IS NULL
```

Before running the delete query, you can run this to make sure it matches the criteria of the data you want removed:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE characterid IS NULL
```

Also, always make sure you make a backup especially when a query like this can affect large sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about PLSQL then I think you can use:

```
 Select characterid
   into //any variable//
   from //tablename
    where //condition
 then you will check 
   if(anyvariable is null)
   then 
      Delete from //tablename
     where //condition
```

Comment: FYI, it is tagged as MySQL

Comment: Yes I know but my information was for Oracle PLSQL. Otherwise you can tansform it into MySQL. The only thing you need  is :                                   Delete from //tablename where characterid = null;